# How to quickly fill a QTableView/Model with data in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, qtableview

I'm looking for a fast way to fill a QTableModel with over 10000 rows of data in python.

Iterating over the items in a double for-loop takes over 40 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly add items to a QTableModel, you can build your own model around an existing data structure like a list of lists or a numpy array like below.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QModelIndex, Qt
import numpy as np

class MyTableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, data=[[]], parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.data = data

    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal:
                return "Column " + str(section)
            else:
                return "Row " + str(section)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.data[0])

    def rowCount(self, parent=None):
        return len(self.data)

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            col = index.column()
            return str(self.data[row][col])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    # data = [[11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
    #         [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
    #         [31, 32, 33, 34, 35]]

    data = np.random.random((10000, 100)) * 100

    model = MyTableModel(data)
    view = QtWidgets.QTableView()
    view.setModel(model)

    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: is this faster than filling a QTableWidget on a for loop?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend creating a numpy array of QStandardItem and filling the Model using the appendColumn function:

```
start = time.time()
data = np.empty(rows, cols, dtype=object)              # generate empty data-Array

#### Fill the data array with strings here ###

items = np.vectorize(QStandardItem)(data)              # generate QStandardItem-Array
print(time.time() - start, "seconds to create items")

start = time.time()
# iterate over columns (because we have segneficantly less columns than rows)
for i in range(len(cols)): 
    self.myQTableModel.appendColumn(items[:,i])

self.myQTableModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headerarray)    # set headers
print(time.time()-start, "seconds to load DB")
```

result for 16000 rows and 7 cols:

```
0.346372127532959 seconds to create items
1.1745991706848145 seconds to load DB
```